# Ruby OptionParser: how to handle arguments without a prefix (like a required filename)

Tags: ruby, command-line-tool, command-line-arguments

I am working with [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) for the first time.

What I would like to know, is how I can make OptionParser handle arguments that are not prefixed with a certain flagname. I want to be able to write a statement like:

```
myscript.rb -d someoption -b someotheroption filename
```

where `filename` is the name of the file I want to work on. It is not prefixed by any option flag. How can I parse commands like the one above with OptionParser, and get a reference to `filename`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OptionParser` specifically handles options - that is, things starting with dashes. After it parses, the remaining arguments are left in `ARGV`. You can check for your filename there and exit with an error if it's missing.

With a slight modification on their [minimal example](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#class-OptionParser-label-Minimal+example),

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
    options[:verbose] = v
  end
end.parse!

p options
p ARGV
p "Where is my hat?!" if ARGV.length == 0
```

You get this:

```
$ ruby parse.rb
{}
[]
"Where is my hat?!"

$ ruby parse.rb hat
{}
["hat"]

$ ruby parse.rb -v hat
{:verbose=>true}
["hat"]
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly.